# Laravel Multiple Queues with Multiple Databases

Tags: laravel, queue, multi-tenant

I have a project with multiple databases, Listing of jobs is done successfully in database but cannot read them, as it switches database at time of executing.
How to persist connection at time of dispatch.

```
$Job = (new \App\Jobs\SchedulingQueue($jobData,"db_".$shop))->onQueue('runJob')->delay(1);
// dispatch($Job);
dispatch($Job);
```

Comment: Just pass the connection name to the job and use that when executing queries within the job.

Comment: I have already tried that with below code- dispatch($job)->onConnection("db_".$shop)

Still facing issue ---
No connector for [] {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): No connector for [] at /..../...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php:172)

Comment: Request cycle completes when the request is made and it dispatches saving the jobs in the database currently mentioned in the request, but as soon as dispatcher dispatches it's job it takes the default connection as the request is over.
So how can we persists that connection over the queue?

Comment: I have successfully implemented this by switching DB at the time of creating jobs, so that jobs are stored in main db. After that ran queue for each database this made multiple queue workers dynamically acting on main database, in the handle part I have switched queues respective db and executed the process. Making it fast and parallel.